# How to minus 1 minute in a variable with format as '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have a variable which holds the date & time as like = '2022-02-27T07:43:00'. (letter "T" is mandatory which is coming from my database by default. I still need that "T" in-between for all the variables). Now I need to minus 1 minute and assign that value to a new variable in the same format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'.

Comment: First thing I recommend is keep track of milliseconds instead of the formatted time and AFTER format then. Doing this you can make any kind of operation with the time (in milliseconds) and after you can format it as you need. Calculate things over a formatted string is a nightmare :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is probably `dateutil.parser.parse` and also `timedelta` function to the trick.

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import timedelta
string = "2022-02-27T07:43:00"
dateObject = parse(string)
oneMinuteBefore = dateObject - timedelta(minutes=1)
oneMinuteBefore.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

##### Output

```
2022-02-27T07:42:00
```

Comment: Thank You so much, This worked perfectly and got the results as expected.

Comment: there also is [isoparse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse) (more efficient) or even a [standard lib method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) (since 3.7) ;-)

Comment: @FObersteiner Thanks for the note! I didn't know about `fromisoformat`.